# Why Google Cloud Storage Image Upload Response Meta Data is not working?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-developers-console

After uploading my images to Google Cloud Storage with [Google's JSON REST APIs Uploading objects guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects), 
  I'm getting this response, but these links are not showing my files, which i uploaded.

How can I fix this problem?

I've noticed something weird after uploading a image in the bucket. The image has the following type:

> image/jpeg; boundary=------------------------534b0c4750bfcf64

What is the meaning of `boundary= -------534b0c4750bfcf64`?

[image: Example of my files]

***Response:***

```
{  
   "kind":"storage#object",
   "id":"testedbucketwow/unnamed.png/1524148551179777",
   "selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/testedbucketwow/o/unnamed.png",
   "name":"unnamed.png",
   "bucket":"testedbucketwow",
   "generation":"1524148551179777",
   "metageneration":"1",
   "contentType":"image/jpeg; boundary=------------------------209e51412cc36b07",
   "timeCreated":"2018-04-19T14:35:51.176Z",
   "updated":"2018-04-19T14:35:51.176Z",
   "storageClass":"MULTI_REGIONAL",
   "timeStorageClassUpdated":"2018-04-19T14:35:51.176Z",
   "size":"49651",
   "md5Hash":"x2gvBrft3kW2LVvHIgcACw==",
   "mediaLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/testedbucketwow/o/unnamed.png?generation=1524148551179777&alt=media",
   "crc32c":"qSwL3g==",
   "etag":"CIG86efHxtoCEAE="
}
```

Comment: Something went wrong with your multipart upload. The `boundary=---...` string is the multipart boundary.

Comment: To clarify the issue, you did not specify the boundary in your request, right? 

Also, could you share the command you used to upload the files? Deleting any sensitive information in it, of course.